# Can't see android Pocophone in Ubuntu 18.04 (usb cable)

Tags: 18.04, usb, android

If I connect the phone (Pocophone f1, xiaomi) to Ubuntu 18.04 it only charges, it seems Ubuntu doesnt see the phone, or the phone doesn't see Ubuntu. Does anyone know anything about? Thanks.

Comment: try changing cables. got a similar problem but changing the cables worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a problem of Android, not Ubuntu. Do this on Android:

1. Open the **Settings** app.
2. Go to **About Phone**
3. Tap **Build Number** 7 times (On the Pocophone, this is called 'MIUI version (for POCO)
4. This should activate **Developer Options**
5. Go to **Settings > Developer Options > Select USB configuration**
6. Select **MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)**

After this Ubuntu (and other OS) should show you the files inside your phone.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If the phone is recognised, this option /should/ appear under the toast notification.

Comment: Could depend on your specific model. I've had this happen with 2 phones on different OS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Install required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gmtp jmtpfs
```

Restart file manager:

```
nautilus -q
```